# Translation Golf XXXIII - The Mirror of Galadriel

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> We have a winner! **user5389726598465**, with [an 54-letter answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24380/16980) (59 with a minor fix), found the shortest translation of the Mirror of Galadriel.

Winner:

> Qué le refleja el espejo mágico, ni **los** listos **lo** saben. Que es, fue, y será. Ve.

<sub>In **bold** minor fix/improvement made by me. (It still is the shortest answer even with the fixes).</sub>

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This edition's proposed text is a quote from [The Lord of the Rings - The Mirror of Galadriel](http://www.kluever-augsburg.de/maria/hdr/drehbuch/englisch/spiegel.html). <sub>(To be exact I found this in a game, and later in La Tertulia [@walen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43074260#43074260) explain me it was from a movie!)</sub>

> Not even the wisest can say *what will you see*, for the *magic* mirror shows many things. Things that are, things that were, and some things that have not yet come to pass... *just look into the mirror*.
>
> <sub>(153 characters)</sub>

<sub>I added the parts in italic in order to make the phrase a bit more large.</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

Here's a (non-golfed) example translation:

> Ni siquiera el más sabio es capaz de decir que verás, el espejo mágico muestra muchas cosas. Muestra cosas que son, muestra cosas que fueron, y algunas otras cosas que aún no han llegado a pasar... simplemente observa el espejo.
>  
>  <sub>(181 characters)</sub>

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: Ender, el juego se ha pasado de fecha (la duración es de una semana). Deberías ir escogiendo un ganador para que este pueda plantear el siguiente reto. :-)

Comment: @Charlie, ya se, pero queria que [user5389726598465](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24380/16980) me respondiera a una pregunta respecto a su traducción ya que el sería el ganador (si es que tiene una explicación de porque realizo así su frase). ¿Espero o eligo a otro (personalmente creo que su frase esta mal traducida)?

Comment: Es costumbre dar algo de margen, aunque normalmente suelen ser algunas horas. Sin embargo ya han pasado dos días y el usuario no da explicación a su traducción. La última palabra la tienes tú, si no te convence pasa a la siguiente. Lo malo es que en ese caso te vas a topar con el primer empate de la historia del TG. Creo que no tenemos criterio de desempate oficial, así que coge el que prefieras: la traducción que te suene más natural, o la que primero alcanzó el número de caracteres actual. Aquí quien pregunta es quien manda y no se le discute. :-)

Comment: @Charlie mi Culpa. Ya estoy de vuelta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**59 caracteres**

> Qué le refleja el espejo mágico, ni los listos lo saben. Que es, fue, y será.
>   Ve.

Comment: No logro comprender correctamente tu traducción. No debería "ni listos saben" ser "ni **los** listos **lo** saben". Además el "Que es, fue, y será" no explica bien de que se esta hablando: ¿Que es, fue y será el espejo? o ¿Que es, fue, y será lo que refleja?

Comment: Even with the fixes your answer is the shortest. You have won the Translation Golf! You have the right to post the new translation golf in the next 2 days!

Comment: @Ender Look Sus comentarios sobre los respuestas demuestran un examen detenido. Procuraré elegir el siguiente pensativamente por ser interesante. Los dos primeros criticas son acertados. El segundo quiza no, porque de otro modo sería "De que" es, fue, y será que no tiene sentido en contexto.

Answer (score 7):

#### 68 caracteres

> Solo mira en el espejo mágico: el hoy, el ayer y el mañana. ¿Qué verás? Ni los sabios saben.

Answer (score 6):

#### 77

> Ni los sabios prevén lo mucho que verás en la [luna](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NhwJXco#A9mx0nA) mágica: lo que fue, es y algo de lo que será. [Ve](http://dle.rae.es/?id=baOo6Gz) y ya.

Answer (score 6):

#### <strike>75</strike> 60 caracteres

> Mira en el espejo mágico, misterio de sabios, visor del ayer, hoy o el mañana.

Aclaraciones:

- Yo siempre he entendido este texto como que el espejo muestra muchos tipos de cosas, no que le vaya a mostrar muchas cosas al que lo ve. Por eso cuando dice que "muestra muchas cosas" enumera los tipos: lo que fue, lo que es, y lo que podrá ser. En la traducción se procede con la enumeración pero se elimina el "muchas" por redundante.
- Como en otras ocasiones, se reordena el texto para enlazar mejor unas frases con otras.
- Comparo el espejo con el visor de las cámaras a través del cual puedes ver el objeto que te interesa fotografiar.

Answer (score 4):

## 60 caracteres

> Ni un genio sabrá lo harto que muestra el espejo. Ayer, hoy, ¿el mañana?. Míralo

Comment: Discúlpame, pero, ¿A que te refieres con harto? Por que de "harto" no creo que te refieras a ["hartar"](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=hartar&rlz=1C1CHZL_esAR710AR710&oq=hartar&aqs=chrome..69i57.760j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), no? No le encuentro el significado en la frase.

Comment: perdón... sería la 3ra acepción del DLE > adj. indef. cult. Mucho o abundante

Answer (score 4):

#### 61 caracteres

> ¿Qué verás en el espejo mágico de lo que fue, es y algo de lo que
>   será? Nadie sabe.

Si ni el mas sabio sabe lo que verás **nadie** lo sabe.

Comment: Discúlpame, pero... ¿En que parte traduces `just look into the mirror`? Creo que seria apropiado añadir algo al respecto. Las demás respuestas dan la orden de mirar a través del espejo (`mira`, `míralo`, `ve y ya`).

Comment: No lo digo porque entendía que al preguntar que verá en el espejo se daba por supuesto que debía mirarlo. Si eso no es suficiente trataré de añadirlo de alguna forma

Comment: Ahh, ya entiendo. La pregunta *sugiere* (*insinúa*) al receptor a mirar a través del espejo. ¡Que astuto! (Deberías incluir la explicación en tu respuesta para que otros lo entiendan mejor también).

Answer (score 4):

## 64 caracteres

> Mira en el espejo mágico que quién sabe si te mostrará el antes, ahora o después.

Llego un poco tarde a la fiesta. Esta es una aportación ciega. Espero no estar utilizando nada de nadie. Comentadme cualquier pega.

Comment: En tu frase no especificas que el espejo es `mágico`. ¿No deberías tal vez decirlo de alguna forma?